# leben auf versus leben in

Tags: preposition

Slow German podcast #185 has the following sentence.

> Sie lebten auf einem Schloss und waren adelig.

Why is it "auf einem Schloss" and not "in einem Schloss"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> auf einem Schloss

This includes the surrounding land and buildings, e.g. you could sleep in a barn, and still be "auf einem Schloss".

> in einem Schloss

You're literally inside the castle building.

It's the same for "auf/in einem Bauernhof".

Answer (score 2):

You can use both.

> Sie leben auf einem Schloss.

*Das Schloss* is a concept. It's a *chic* form of living.

> Sie leben in einem Schloss.

*Das Schloss* is a building.

(Note Austrian German is more picky and insists on *in* AFAIK.)

Comment: I can't follow your differentiation of "Schloss" as a concept versus a building, in this context. (I do well understand the principal idea of a concept versus a building, but I don't see it in this context.) Both "sie lebt auf dem Schloss" and "sie lebt im Schloss" for me are related to living in a certain type of building.

Comment: *Auf einem Schlossberg* would fit. They don't live on the roof. But if someone said that, I assumed they lived in one of the servant's houses, not in the actual *Schloss*.

Comment: Where I grew up (Southern Germany) there is, in oral language, no practical difference between "auf" and "in" for "Schloss". - *Wo wohnt die Gräfin? - Die Gräfin wohnt im Schloss da drüben / Die Gräfin wohnt auf dem Schloss da drüben.* - Okay, well, you could perhaps argue that *im Schloss* would mean the building in the narrower sense, whereas  *auf dem Schloss* could also refer to the entire complex including courtyard, agricultural buildings and what ever.

Comment: For me (Ruhrgebiet, Germany) _in Schloss Lembeck leben_ would mean 'dort wohnen', and _auf Schloss Lembeck leben_ would be 'hochherrschaftlich leben' (to live lordly).